# PaClient error: E0002 Missing profile name

Tags: android, delphi

I try to make an android application in delphi but when i build the project i get this error:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E0002 Missing profile name; use paclient -?
>   for Help

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does this happen with a fresh new Android targeted project as well? If so, can you post a small screenshot on the selected Android device and profile from the project manager? Like this one from http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2013/11/23/43005 : http://blogs.embarcadero.com/files/2013/11/projectmanager_10030-285x300.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building Android applications in delphi, [you do not use the PAServer nor PAClient](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development), so there is no profile: these are [only needed for iOS or OS X development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connection_Profile_Manager#When_You_Must_Use_a_Connection_Profile).

To figure out what is calling [PAClient](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Paclient.exe,_the_Platform_Assistant_Client_Application) and why the call fails, follow these steps:

1. Run Delphi while the free [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals is active,
2. watch the Process Monitor log to see when the PAClient is executed, and what parameters there are.
3. Relate these parameters to the selected profile

Note that error [E00002](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E0002_Missing_profile_name) means the PAClient has no profile name in the parameters.

Comment: Can you please explane more about step 3?

Answer (score 1):

You may check your configuration as well in Delphi XE 8.1:

Build Configuration: RELEASE
Android: APPLICATION STORE

For instance DEBUG and APPLICATION STORE may result in a E00002 error.

Answer (score 0):

Also check Project -> Deployment that all items are checked. That worked for me.
(I unchecked all items by mistake when adding some files for deployment manually)

Via FFernandes https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=118789