# "[PAClient Error] Error: E0002 Missing profile name" error when running my application on a Phone connected via USB

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to to run a application on my android device. The issue is that I get the PAClient error `E0002` From my understanding profile names are only needed when running apps on Remote Devices, which I'm not doing. There are no profiles created for the PAClient and even if i try to create one the only option is Widows 64 and 32-Bit

I recently reinstalled the Android Common Files from Tools -> Manage Platforms. That could have something to do with it. I know there is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286594/paclient-error-e0002-missing-profile-name), but that post has no working answers.

[image]

Also here are my computers environment variables
[image]

My platform selector [image]

So how do I fix this error?

Comment: It's possible your machine has an environment variable that clashes with what Delphi uses. Usually, it's PLATFORM. Removing the environment variable may fix the problem

Comment: @DaveNottage There is no `PLATFORM` environment variable in the System Variables nor in the User Variables on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer:

The PAClient Error was caused by a compatibility issue with the device in question and the Android SDK Installed the computer.
To fix this issue go to `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\<Your Installed SDK>\` open `SDK Manager.exe`, remove the SDK installed (Ex: Android 10) and install the one corresponding to the Android Version on your phone (Android R Dev. Preview in my case). Then open Delphi, go to Tools -> Options -> Deployment -> Sdk Manager then change the path of the old SDKs to the new SDK path (They should have a exclamation mark next to them). Now the last thing you have to do is go to the Java Tab and change the `Keytool` and `Jarsigner` location to a valid one if its not already valid (something like `C:\ProgramFiles\<your java installation>\<java jdk version>\bin\keytool.exe` and `C:\ProgramFiles\<your java installation>\<java jdk version>\bin\jarsigner.exe` for the jarsigner).

That's all. Now you can compile & run your application on your device.

Note: You don't have to uninstall the old SDK if you still need it to make apps for other android versions. Only remove it if you don't need it.