# Cannot deploy Android project because I get [PAClient Error] E0002 Missing profile name

Tags: android, delphi

I've been working on an Android app in Delphi (10.4, Multi-Device Application ) and I want to post it on Google Play AppStore.

The app builds just fine for both 32 and 64 platforms, but when I try to deploy it I get "[PAClient Error] Error: E0002 Missing profile name; use paclient -? for Help".

As far as I read PAClient is only necessary for iOS apps deployment, so I went ahead and cleaned my project of iOS refferences ( targets, configurations, everything I could find). It doesn't make sense for the error to come up when trying to deploy Android app...

I've tried downloading new SDK/NDK packages and creating new profiles in the Delphi Options/Deployment/SDKManager.

Still I get same error when trying to deploy the app for Android.

[image: Screenshot of the error in Delphi after clicking Deploy]

No solution found on StackOverflow or in other sources worked

I'm open for suggestions as to what I can try to make the app deploy without error

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[PAClient Error\] Error: E0002 Missing profile name" error when running my application on a Phone connected via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217460/paclient-error-error-e0002-missing-profile-name-error-when-running-my-appli)